# How do I get access to the underlying threadpool/fork join pool for an Akka Actor System

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, akka-stream

I have this type safe config for creating an akka actor config

```
akka = {
    coordinated-shutdown = {
        run-by-jvm-shutdown-hook = off
    }
    loglevel = "ERROR"
    loggers = ("akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger")
    logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}

dispatchers = {
    stream = {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = fork-join-executor
        fork-join-executor = {
            parallelism-min = 50
            parallelism-max = 50
        }
    }

    other = {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        throughput = 1

        thread-pool-executor = {
            fixed-pool-size = 500
        }
    }
}
```

And I define the actor system as such

```
val akkaConfig: Config = readConfigFromFile()
val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("foo-actor-system", akkaConfig)
```

Now I am trying to understand the behavior of my dispatcher threads, specifically the stream dispatcher.

I am interested in getting the values of active thread count and running thread count, from the underlying fork join pool

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html
```

1. Is it possible to get the underlying thread pool handle, so that I can just query the method.
2. Should I instead configure the Config manually somehow, and inject the thread pool instead. If so, how would I go about accomplishing that?
3. I do not necessarily need the thread pool handle either. I am trying to get metrics.

Comment: If all you want is the metrics, either Kamon or Lightbend Telemetry should be able to get the job done.